# Setting a Threshold for fuzzywuzzy process.extractOne

Tags: python-3.x, fuzzywuzzy

I'm currently doing some string product similarity matches between two different retailers and I'm using the **fuzzywuzzy** `process.extractOne` *function* to find the best match.

However, I want to be able to set a scoring threshold so that the product will only match if the score is above a certain threshold, because currently it is just matching every single product based on the closest string.

The following code gives me the best match: (currently getting errors)

`title, index, score = process.extractOne(text, choices_dict)`

I then tried the following code to try set a threshold:

`title, index, score = process.extractOne(text, choices_dict, score_cutoff=80)`

Which results in the following TypeError:

`TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object`

Finally, I also tried the following code:

`title, index, scorer, score = process.extractOne(text, choices_dict, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio, score_cutoff=80)`

Which results in the following error:

`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process.extractOne` will return None, when the best score is below `score_cutoff`. So you either have to check for None, or catch the exception:

```py
best_match = process.extractOne(text, choices_dict, score_cutoff=80)
if best_match:
    value, score, key = best_match
    print(f"best match is {key}:{value} with the similarity {score}")
else:
    print("no match found")
```

or

```py
try:
    value, score, key = process.extractOne(text, choices_dict, score_cutoff=80)
    print(f"best match is {key}:{value} with the similarity {score}")
except TypeError:
    print("no match found")
```

Comment: Thank you - I think I was setting the score cut-off too high and it was causing the error. I've experimented with lower thresholds and I'm getting results now.

I wouldn't have realised this without your assistance. Thanks again.